# Seeking a translation for a specific use of the English word "claim"

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, verbs

**tl;dr: Is "pretendi" an appropriate translation of the English "to claim" in the sense of an insurance claim?**

According to ReVo, "to claim" is simply "pretendi". However, the definitions (there and in PIV) seem only to describe the idea of claiming "the throne" or "a right" or something similar.

I'm wanting to describe the idea of claiming a sum of money, in the sense of an insurance claim. In the Macquarie Dictionary (I'm Australian, that's the "real" English dictionary to me) there's one definition I'm looking for:

```
a payment demanded in accordance with an insurance policy, etc.
```

Dictionary.com has an almost identical one:

```
a request or demand for payment in accordance with an insurance policy,
a workers' compensation law, etc.:
```

... as well as the verb form.

```
to make or file a claim:
```

These definitions don't really fit with the ones that PIV gives but could the word work appropriately?

I'm thinking "pretendi" for "to claim" and maybe "pretendaĵo" (or simply "pretendo") for "a claim".

Answer (score 5):

[John Well](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176)’s dictionary has the following:

> **claim** pretend-i, -o; postul-i, -o; reklamaci-i, -o; asert-i, -o

I think *reklamacii* could be a suitable word. It has the following definition in PIV:

> **reklamaci/i** (ntr) Turni sin al oficisto ks, postulante, ke la ŝuldata servo estu plenumita; plende depostuli ion, kion oni rajtas ricevi: *nericevinto bonvolu reklamacii*.
>
> **reklamacio**. Ago k vortoj de tiu, kiu reklamacias.

This could be translated as:

> Go to an official, demanding that the service owed be fulfilled.

I think once the criteria for claiming an insurance policy have been met then it could be considered a service owed and the definition of the word fits the action.

Comment: I agree. It fits perfectly with what I'm using it for (insurance was just the best way I could describe it in the question).

Answer (score 4):

[Majstro](http://www.majstro.com/Web/Majstro/adict.php?gebrTaal=fra&bronTaal=eng&doelTaal=epo&teVertalen=claim) gives several other possible translation, including *aserti*, *postuli* and *reklamacii*. The later seems a good fit for what your are looking for I think.

Please let me know if it does fit or not. Cheers.

Comment: That's great. Tell me... why haven't I used majstro.com before?

Answer (score 3):

I find the following two resources a great way to answer questions like this on your own.

http://www.esperanto-me.org/dic/

vortaro.net

Look up the English word in the first link and then check the result at the second. Doing so makes me think that you would want *reklamacio* or *depostulo*.

Comment: The teacher in Tomaso is showing... Give a man a fish, teach a man to fish etc... But in  all seriousness, thanks for that link. That and majstro.com will be very useful in the future.

Comment: I thought it was a great question, and I ran through these same steps to find an answer -- then I thought "why not share the process." Glad it helped. I am glad you're already checking PIV before asking. Quite honestly, I hadn't quite noticed that before posting. (Shame on me.)